# WebGL backend for tensorflowjs loads the model (blazeface) very late

Tags: tensorflow, webgl, tensorflow.js

I am trying to add blazeface model to my application. I have just figured out that when I use WebGL backend, the first call of estimateFaces()

```
 console.log("estimate started") 
        const predictions = await model.estimateFaces(
          this.refVideo.current,
          returnTensors,
          flipHorizontal,
          annotateBoxes
        );
 console.log("estimate finished") // first time it is very slow with WebGL
```

is taking almost 18 seconds. Which is not the case for WASM or CPU backend. You can also feel the difference at [blazeface demo](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/blazeface/index.html). Set the backend to WebGL from the upper right menu and open your cam. First mask of the face detection loads way way later than with WASM or cpu backends. Do you have any idea why is it happening?

tensors are below:

```js
       if (predictions.length > 0) {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          for (let i = 0; i < predictions.length; i++) {
            if (returnTensors) {
              predictions[i].topLeft = predictions[i].topLeft.arraySync();
              predictions[i].bottomRight = predictions[i].bottomRight.arraySync();
              if (annotateBoxes) {
                predictions[i].landmarks = predictions[i].landmarks.arraySync();
              }
            }
            try {
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err.message);
            }
            this.portraitMode = false;
            if (videoWidth < videoHeight && window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
                this.portraitMode = true;
            }
            drawRoiOnCanvas(canvas, ctx, predictions[i], this.portraitMode, this.setDisableButtons)
            
          }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(this.renderPrediction);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Perhaps the issue is in how the tensors are being passed to the model. Could you include how you are doing that?

Comment: sure, I edited the question.

Comment: Are you using React Native by any chance?

Comment: I am using reactjs

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue has something to do with the time it takes the weights of Blazeface to get loaded into the GPU. I had this same issue while importing Facemesh. Whenever I loaded it in with a `wasm` backend then changed the backend to `webgl` it would lag for ~5 seconds before working properly. What worked for me was setting the backend to `webgl` before loading in the Facemesh model.